# Real Analysis - discontinuity

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f(x)$ = $x^2$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)$ = $0$ if $x$ is irrational.

Prove that that $x$ is discontinuous at all $x\neq 0$

We look at the case where $x\neq 0$ and $x\in R\setminus Q$

Proof

Let $\epsilon = x^2/10$
and let $0 \lt \Delta \lt |x|/2$

Due to denseness of irrationals there exists a rational number $q$ in $(a-\Delta,a+\Delta)$.
By the triangle inequality $|q| \gt |x|/2$ $\implies$ $f(q) = x^2/4$ $\implies$ $|f(x)-f(q)|=x^2/4>\epsilon$. Since $\Delta$ can be made arbitrarily small $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

First, it is not clear to me how $\Delta$ can be made arbitrarily small. Second, since $|q| \gt |x|/2$, shouldn't $f(q)$ be greater than rather than equal to $x^2/4$. I have problems following the logic of this specific proof in general.

Comment: To get $|f(x)-f(q)|=x^2/4>\epsilon$ you only need $0<\Delta <|x|/2$ . So you can take $\Delta$ as small as you want.

Answer (score 0):

- To illustrate that $\Delta$ can be made arbitrarily small, let me construct the following sequence, $\Delta_n = \frac{|x|}{2^n}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$.

Since $\Delta_n$ converges to zero, $\Delta$ can be made arbitrarily small.

It seems that there are some typos in the proof.

We have $f(q) = q^2$, since $q$ is rational. Also, for the case where $x$ is irrational, $f(x) = 0$. Hence, we have $$|f(q) - f(x)|=|f(q)|=q^2>\frac{x^2}{4}>\frac{x^2}{10}=\epsilon$$

Comment: Thank you. But if the delta gets very small; lets say |x|/8, then f(q) will end up being x^2/64 which is less than epsilon. This where I get confused.

Comment: If $\Delta = \frac{|x|}8$, then $q \in (x-\frac{|x|}8, x+\frac{|x|}8)$, then $|q|>\frac78|x|$, $|f(q)|=q^2>\frac{49}{64}|x|^2>\frac{x^2}{10}=\epsilon$

Comment: note that $f(q)$, i.e. $f$ evaluted at $q$ should be a function of $q$ and not $x$.